# How to search for images in the browser with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a plugin for Chrome just for fun, but I'm having problems with this specific part:

1. I have an input field
2. We insert a value in here, for example: cats
3. The goal is to look for every image in the browser page (the active tab) that it's a cat or cat related
4. Change every cat image for something else.

Does anyone have any idea how to take the input given an search for the images ?
I thought about using the alt and title attributes, but that is to fallible, I wanted something that wouldn't fail like the Google Search Images.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think Google might be spending millions of dollars trying to solve this problem!

Comment: you should add machine learning and AI tag as well. its not just plain JavaScript thingy :P

Comment: @sandeepjoshi can you tell me a bit more about what I have to do ? Maybe advice me some links to read, etc...